# How to get least value in Array

Tags: java

```
int[] smallest = {4,5,1,3,7};
System.out.println(getMinimum(smallest));
```

---

```
public static int getMinimum(int[] a){
    int min = a[0];

    for (int i = 0; i <a.length; i++){
        if(a[i] < min){
            min = a[i];
        }

    }
    return min;
}
```

This (above) works but this (below) doesn't:

```
int[] smallest = {4,5,1,3,7};
System.out.println(getMinimum(smallest));
```

---

```
public static int getMinimum(int[] a){
    int min = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <a.length; i++){
        if(a[i] < min){
            min = a[i];
        }

    }
    return min;
}
```

I can't figure out why, in the top example `getMinimum` returns `1`, but in the bottom example `getMinimum` returns `3`? Both are doing the same thing yet one is wrong and the other right? Is it because I assigned min to equal `0`?

Comment: In the top case it returns 1, not -1, doesn't it?

Comment: 2nd example is simply wrong. It does not calculate a minimum.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/3788176)

Answer (score 2):

In your second example you're always comparing against `a[0]`, not against whatever your current minimum value is.  As a result, the answer you get will always be the last number in the array that is smaller than the value in `a[0]` which in your case is 3

If your intention was to sort the array, as the title of your question implies, then you probably meant to put the minimum value into `a[0]` each time it was updated.  This wouldn't actually sort the array correctly but it would put you on the right track and fix the comparison problem

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem of your second version is nicely solved in the answer by rdowell.

However, after fixing it by comparing to `min` instead to always `a[0]` you will have a second problem.

If you init `min` with 0 it is not possible to find a lower value, at least not among the positive values of your example.
Initialising it with `a[0]` uses a possible value and the others can be lower.
If you do not want to init with first element, then init higher than any value can be.
For the single-digit example "10" would be a good value, then already the first value is lower and the others have a chance, too.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, change

```
if(a[i] < a[0])
```

to

```
if(a[i] < min)
```

That is the discernment. Doesn't have anything to do with you setting min to 0 or a[0]. Especially since in the second example you don't even compare a[i] to min.

Answer (score 0):

You are always comparing the first value in the `Array` when you should be comparing to the previous smallest value. The second example never calculates a minimum since `min` is set to `0` and unless the `Array` contains negative values, `min` will stay as `0`. The following code should work:

```
public static int getMinimum(int[] a){
int min = a[0];

for (int i = 0; i <a.length; i++){
    if(a[i] < min){
        min = a[i];
    }

}
return min;
}
```